# Как сделать Image Button в Activity с помощью переменной из другого Activity

Tags: android, activity, android-intent, imagebutton

У меня есть, например, activity_car, в разметке я делаю кнопку, и вешаю на неё onClick. В классе я указываю, что при нажатии на кнопку она переводит меня на другое activity_main, и захватывает за собой переменную. В activity_main я делаю проверку. Если переменная равна единице, то в activity_main появляется Image Button. У меня уже есть код для этого, но к сожалению, виджет появляется сразу, по необъяснимым причинам. Вот код:
 1. Отправка Integer из activity_car:

```
public void newBtn(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(car.this, Main2Activity.class);
        intent.putExtra("value", 1);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

2. Код в activity_main:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Integer value = intent.getIntExtra("value", 1);

LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainmain);



if (value == 1) {
     openFunc();
}

private void openFunc() {
   ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
   imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams = new 
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
   imageView.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);
   mainLayout.addView(imageView);
}
```

Comment: в MainActivity - `Integer value = intent.getIntExtra("value", 0);` - здесь вторым аргументом указывается значение по умолчанию, оно будет присвоено, если никакого значения получено не было, указывая здесь 1 вы присваиваете 1 в любом случае - и когда передаете его из другой активити и когда ничего не передаете. ps: передавать логичнее булево значение (true/false) а не число

Comment: Да, спасибо, сейчас попробую. Я не могу передавать это значение, потому что виджеты появляться будут у меня в зависимости от значения переменной

Comment: @pavlofff У меня проблема в том, что Image Button появляется сразу, даже если есть условие, что оно должно появиться, если значение value равно единице

Comment: Главный activity - activity_main, с него запускается приложение (в нём есть кнопка для перехода в activity_car).
Ожидание: в activity_car я нажимаю кнопку. Intent берёт с собой integer, и перекидывает меня в activity_main. В классе MainActivity происходит проверка. Если integer равен единице, то в activity_main появляется Image Button.
Реальность: как только открывается приложение, этот Image Button уже появляется

Comment: вы изменили 1 на 0 как я писал в первом коментарии и ничего не изменилось?

Comment: Извините, не заметил. Мне показалось, что вы написали 1 вместо 0. Сейчас попробую...

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Вы не представляете, как помогли мне!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

в MainActivity:

```
Integer value = intent.getIntExtra("value", 0);
```

здесь вторым аргументом указывается значение по умолчанию, оно будет присвоено, если никакого значения получено не было.
Указывая здесь 1 вы присваиваете 1 в любом случае - и когда передаете его из другой активити и когда ничего не передаете, поэтому значение по умолчанию должно быть отличным от передаваемых из других активити значений, например 0